# how to create a check box in j2me?

Tags: java-me

I am developing my first project. I have to create a check box and based on the selection it should give a output.

Answer (score 1):

use "J2ME:Complete Reference". Best book for begineers. as i also started learning J2ME recently,i found it very useful.It is easily available for download [here](http://dev.10086.cn/cmdn/supesite/newdev.tool.php?type=download&id=1145&attachid=1320).